# Warning when using BibLaTeX for a Spanish article, it does not print the citations or references

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, apacite, spanish

I am trying to create a Spanish article template using BibLaTeX (because using natbib print "and" instead of "y" (or "&")). However, when I compile it, it does not print neither the citations nor the references at the end. I suspect it is something related to my system or the LaTeX engine I am using, because when I run it on Overleaf, it works fine. However, I want to stop using Overleaf because it takes too long to compile and it requires me to purchase a license for the compilation time. I am using Windows 11 with the TexStudio editor and Texlive 2023-20230313, and below I am attaching the code. The warning that appears is "main.tex: warning: 42: Citation 'giancoli2014' on page 1 undefined.But the citation is correctly listed in the file referencias.bib.

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{referencias.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red!50!black,linkcolor=red!50!black,citecolor=red!50!black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
 \usepackage{palatino}
    
\title{Título del artículo}
\author{Nombre del autor}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[15]
    
    \bigskip
    \noindent\textbf{Palabras clave:} palabra clave 1, palabra clave 2, palabra clave 3
\end{abstract}

\section{Introducción}
\lipsum[1]

Formas de referenciar

Paréntesis:
\parencite{giancoli2014}

Textual:
\textcite{giancoli2014}
\parencite{young2009}
\textcite{young2009}
\textcite{bevington1993}
\parencite{bevington1993}

\section{Metodología}
\lipsum[5-6]

\section{Resultados}
\lipsum[7-8]

\section{Análisis y Discusión}
\lipsum[9-10]

\section{Conclusiones}
\lipsum[11-12]

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

The code print the citations as shown in the image:
[image]

Any idea how to fix the error?

Comment: After compiling, you need to run `biber` and then recompile at least once. This is something Overleaf does for you. Most editors do not. What you're seeing is not an error. This is, in fact, the expected output.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 to see how to configure your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Thaks, it works!!